# Problema para obtener resultado de un procedimiento almacenado en c#

Tags: c#, stored-procedure

Tengo que pasar información que tengo en un procedimiento almacenado a unas listas, Este es el resultado de mi procedimiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Voy a hacer el ejercicio acá pero con la primera columna que viene a ser la del `nro_item`, teniendo esto creo una lista en donde voy a almacenar esos tres valores:

```
public static List<int> NumeroItem = new List<int>();
```

La función es la siguiente:

```
public static void ObtenerItems(int Ndoc, int Cdoc)
{
    AbrirConexion();
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
    comando.Connection = conexion;
    comando.CommandText = "Sp_c_XML_DocIngreso 'C'," + Ndoc + "," + Cdoc;

    var reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //elementos que rescato de mi base de datos y los guardo en listas
        NumeroItem.Add(Int32.Parse(reader[0].ToString()));
        MessageBox.Show(NumeroItem[0].ToString());

    }
}
```

Abro la conexión, declaro el procedimiento y los valores que le mando y después ejecuto, estuve leyendo que para este caso lo mejor es usar `ExecuteReader` porque así obtengo el conjunto de los datos.

Después dentro de un `while` voy leyendo y asigno, acá es donde creo que estoy mal. Porque:

1. `NumeroItem.add()` : creo un elemento de la lista
2. `Int32.Parse:` esta parte no creo que tenga que explicarla
3. `reader[]` -> acá es donde creo que estoy llamando mal para poder sacar el `nro_item`, está bien?

Porque abajo puse un `MessageBox` para ver si me traía bien el dato, el valor 1 y me muestra un numero 14 que no sé de donde sale.

Ojalá alguien me pueda orientar, no creo estar tan perdido.

Muchas gracias

Comment: puedes agregar la salida del Stored procedure para ver que esta mapeando mal? tambien no olvides cerrar tu conexion y tu reader. reader.Close();
            comando.Connection.Close();

Comment: Ensaya primero ´MessageBox.Show(reader[0].ToString());´, para verificar si te muestra el mismo error, te recomiendo que escribas tambien el procedimiento por que como solo has puesto fracciones del código es difícil determinar de donde viene el error, si del procedimiento, de la variable NumeroItem u otra parte.

Comment: Si estás llamando a un procedimiento almacenado, debes informarselo al SqlCommand. Prueba a añadir `comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` en tu código

Comment: Gracias, a los 3 por su ayuda. no sabía que tenia que cerrar las conexiones. Ensayé como me dijo Weimar y encontré un error y también me faltaba lo del CommandType